# How to specify language when using highlight.js?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I'm using highlight.js to highlight code blocks in HTML. highlight.js can find all code blocks and determine the language automatically but I would like to specify both element(s) and language(s) manually. By specifying the language I would like to avoid overhead of determining which language it is (although highlight.js is fast, it could be faster if it would skip the language detection, I guess).

In HTML I specify the language as a class (I need this for some styling of the code block).

```
<pre>
<code class="python">
print "Hello"
</code>
</pre>
```

In JavaScript I iterate over the code elements (for some other reason I need to get a list of these elements). When I'm iterating over the code elements, I call `hljs.highlightBlock` function. Because I know the language (stored as class), I think it would be advantageous to actually tell highlight.js the language it should highlight.

From the usage examples on highlight.js web site I guessed that I can call `hljs.configure` function and specify a list of languages to try:

```
// ...
if (codeElement.hasClass('python'))
    language = 'python';
else if (codeElement.hasClass('bash'))
    language = 'bash';

hljs.configure({languages: [language]});
hljs.highlightBlock(codeElement[0]);
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. First, it is not clear to me if this is an official API I can rely on. Second, I think that highlight.js is still trying to determine if the code block is in the given language or not (which is what I wanted to avoid in the first place).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are iterating over 'pre code' elements right? But you specified the language in the 'code' tag instead of the 'pre' tag.
I had the same problem and specifiyng the language on the topmost element fixed the issue. Your html code should look like this:

```
<pre class="python">
<code>
print "Hello"
</code>
</pre>
```

Also make sure that 'python' is included in the highlight.js pack that you are using :)

Comment: I know the answer works, but it smacks of imprecision. It is okay to know that something works, but it is important to know how. The code in the question is what the docs indicate and if it doesn't work then there is a bug. Five years has passed since and his original code probably works now.

Comment: It is clearly outlined in the docs, that laugage detection is used unless the appropriate class is set on the element that is passed to `hljs.highlightBlock` (and that is in this case the <pre> element)
See https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#highlightblock-block

Comment: I think i should add that Highlight JS looks for blocks that resemble a `<pre><code></code></pre>` tags as specified in [Highlight Usage](https://highlightjs.org/usage/). However, it is possible to change this behavior and set a custom block to look for using this:

`document.querySelectorAll('your custom block goes here').forEach((block) => {
  hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});`

Comment: As of 2020, `code` now contains the `class`, see [fit](https://highlightjs.org/usage/)

Answer (score 1):

**As of 2023:**

```js
const highlightedCode = hljs.highlight('print "hello"', { language: 'python' }).value

document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = `<code>${highlightedCode}</code>`
```

```css
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, SF Mono, Menlo, Consolas,
    Liberation Mono, monospace;
  background-color: #f6f8fa;
  padding: 1rem;
}

code {
  white-space: break-spaces;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-break: normal;
  white-space: pre;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<pre id="code"></pre>
```